# Slope increasing despite global maximum decreasing.

Tags: recreational-mathematics

If we let $s(x)=\sin(x)$, and $s^n(x)$ is the $n$'th iteration of $s(x)$, and $$f(x)=s^n(x)-s^{n}(\frac{\pi}{2})s(x)$$For some constant $n$. As we increase $n$ from $0$, the global maximum increases, but then after $n=16$, it decreases again, and will converge to $0$, since $s^{\infty}(x)=0$.

Also, the slope at $x=0$ will increase as $n$ increases, why is the slope increasing and not decreasing like the global maximum?

Comment: What do you mean by iteration of $s(x)$? is $s^2(x) = s(s(x))$?

Comment: yes. It is. Need more characters to comment.

Comment: I do not see this behavior when I plot these functions.  Could you share your evidence for these claims? Some plots would do. Cheers!

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nppyvrh5qk Sorry for the late reply, had class. This one shows the increasing slope.